# Windows Universal app - the right project structure

Tags: android, windows, visual-studio

I am new in Visual Studio development, and I'd like to understand the structure of the project, being android dev. for a while, I think there are some similarities between Android Studio structure and Visual Studio. Well, in an android project there is generated a very clean structure `/java` where we have java classes - we can create packets for clarity, then we have `/res` with `/drawable`, `/layout`, `/values`..., we have `AndroidManifest.xml` file with all app permissions and some other declaration stuff, `build.gradle` where we can include used libs. In Visual Studio is a bit confusing for me with `.xaml` `.xaml.cs` `.cs`, no structure ... If anybody can explain me in a brief or indicate some links, I'll appreciate.

Have to notice that I'd like to use `C#` and `xaml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is the basic:
`Package.appxmanifest` is the AndroidManifest.xml, it contains app permissions, background task, app title and visual...

You have to create folders yourself, usually I use `View`, `ViewModel` and `Model` for `MVVM`. If you use other framework then it depend.

`Assets` is the folder you put icons, logos, fonts, etc inside

UWP app not use gradle for package management, we use Nuget, right click on the project and click `Manage Nuget Packages`. `project.json` is the file it generate.

Its for the basic project. If you need something more complex, then you can use other structures to suit your need.

Happy coding for UWP.